# link hover css styling issue

Tags: css

I was wondering if link hover style as in the image is possible using pure css or we need to use background images, js or jquery etc. to achieve this!

[image]

Any examples would be highly appreciated :)
Thanks,

Comment: Have you actually tried something?

Comment: I think this is an background image.

Comment: oh yes I did, just was looking for suggestions..

Comment: SO is built on the idea that you if you have a problem that you have tried to solve, but are stuck, ask us! BUT! Show your work! Give us your code examples of what you have tried and we'll be more than happy to help you :)

Comment: well I have the links done with the hover over background color, that's easy stuff, I'm stuck on mousehover image display thingy, googling about it right now :P

not necessarily looking for code but suggestions about how to do it :)

Comment: Background image with position `50% 100%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way (if you, for example, need to support Internet Explorer or want a custom arrow) is to use a background at `50% 100%`

HTML:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Another link</a></li>
</ul>
```

​
CSS:

```
li { float: left; padding-bottom: 16px; }
li:hover { background: 50% 100% no-repeat url(http://www.staypoland.com/images/arrow-city-up.gif); }
a { float: left; }
a:hover { background: blue; }​
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/Mcz3P/

Answer (score 1):

You can use a css pseudo classe  :after  , to create the arrow. This can reduce the meaning-less HTML code.

HTML:

```
<div class="div">
      About Us
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
.div {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #09f;
    border: 2px solid #09f;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;
}
.div:after {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    bottom: -10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px;
    border-color:  transparent transparent #09f transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
}

​
```

You can see the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/JMaV8/

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible with pure CSS, without any image. You can find very cool things for example on [CSSdeck](http://cssdeck.com/search/?q=menu) that might interest you. Also @afshin 's demo is good example of from where you can start doing it. So go on...

Comment: yep I'm working on @afshin's example. thanks for the link, really useful.